# References for doing geometry using "higher degree curves as fundamental objects."

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In a typical introduction to coordinate geometry, we fix a couple of intersecting lines in an affine plane and then parameterise points via coordinates. Treating "points as fundamental objects" means that all other geometric objects are given by equations whose solutions are points.

On the other hand, we can treat "lines as fundamental objects": We can define points via pencil of lines (although two lines in the pencil uniquely determine the pencil). After fixing three non-concurrent lines (i.e. a special triangle), we can obtain ("abridged") homogenous coordinates for all the lines in the plane and conics circumscribing the special triangle. This approach can be found in old books (say, A treatise on conic sections by Salmon). In this approach, certain theorems of geometry become simple. One can prove Pascal's theorem on conics, using this approach (it can be found in Felix Klein's "Geometry from an advanced viewpoint").

It looks like one can similarly consider "conics as fundamental objects". For instance, a point can then be represented by the pencil of conics passing through that point. In other words, a point will be specified by 5 homogenous coordinates. Conics passing through a line will be given by 3 homogenous coordinates that represent the line and so on.

My question is: **What are some references, say in modern algebraic geometry, that treat "higher degree curves as fundamental objects" and parametrises (coordinatizes?) other geometric objects using higher degree curves?**

Comment: I think you are looking for the general notion of a parameter space, of which the Hilbert scheme (the cleanest way of generalizing the Grassmanian of linear subspaces to arbitrary subschemes of a projective scheme [e.g. curves in $\mathbb P^n$]) is the most important example.